# How to perform addition of two dataframe columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different sizes and I am trying to perform an addition of values from a common column found in both dataframes based on matching values in another common column.
My first dataframe looks like this:

df1

```
ID   name     region  earnings
101  Joseph   A       100
102  Adam     A       200
103  Clint    C       150
104  Mark     C       60
105  Michael  A       0
```

df2 looks like this

```
ID   earnings
101   20
103   40
105   60
```

My expected results is

```
ID   name     region  earnings
101  Joseph   A       120
102  Adam     A       200
103  Clint    C       190
104  Mark     C       60
105  Michael  A       60
```

How would I go about this please? My first thought was to iterate over every line but then I read that this is discouraged as it has poor performance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` + `set_index` + `fillna`:

```
df1['earnings'] += df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['earnings']).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    ID     name region  earnings
0  101   Joseph      A       120
1  102     Adam      A       200
2  103    Clint      C       190
3  104     Mark      C        60
4  105  Michael      A        60
```

Comment: a great piece of work. However, a classic example of where python simplies the problem to a one line solution, but actually the solution becomes unreadable.

Comment: @D.L you find it unreadable? Just break it down - it's actually really simple. :)

Comment: Great, this works however the output it gives me is different than what I achieved with a for loop on my actual data. The difference is only 0.71 but it is there. What might be the reason behind this? And by manual counting, the for loop gets the right result.

Comment: I'm not sure why that might be happening...can you show the culprit row(s) from the dataframes?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I am stupid. This works perfectly. Thank you very much. I messed up, cause I just needed to change astype() to float as I have data with floating point